# How can I use ffmpeg to crop a part of a video by frames numbers including video and audio?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I have a simple list:

```
LReg.start = rise[i];
LReg.end = fall[i];
LR.Add(LReg);
```

start and end are int's in the end I have a List of the frames I want to extract from a video file. For example in index 0 of LR I have start 48 end 51
In index 1 start 110 end 124

So I want to loop over the List an save as a video file the part of a video file using ffmpeg according to the frame number start and end by jumping to this frames.
Jump to frame 48 and create a video file out from frame 48 to 51 including 48 and 51. Then jump forward to the next group of frames 110 and 124 and so on.

The problem is how to use ffmpeg to extract and save video files ?

Comment: What I mean is to use the frames as start-end positions in the video file and then cut this part of the video file and save it as a video file so in the end I will have the part from frame 48 to 51 as a video file with audio ! Not to extract the frames and create video file from them but using the frames as position to crop the part of the video from.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) and [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]select='between(n,48,51)+between(n,110,124)+between(n,150,181)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v]" -map "[v]" output
```

Comment: Didn't realize you wanted audio until after I answered. It would be easier to deal with if you could use timestamps instead of frame numbers. If that's a possibility I'll update the answer.